# How to stop Express.js route from next()?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have a weird situation...

I have a Express.js, Node.js and Mongoose web app.

One of the routes has a mongoose callback that calls respond.send(...). However, because there is nothing else after the callback, I suspect it goes to next() route automatically.

Ex:

```
//getItem 
app.get('/api/ItemOne', isUserValid, routes.getItem); 
//getAnotherItem
app.get('/api/getAnotherItem', isUserValid, routes.getAnotherItem);

//Routes
exports.getItem = function (req, res) {
  //console.log ('In getItem'); 
   getItem .findOne({ some_id : some_id}, function(err, getItem ){
      //console.log ('In getItem callback');
      res.send({
         itemName : getItem .itemName,
         itemValue : getItem .itemValue;
      });
   })
});

exports.getAnotherItem = function (req, res) { 
   //console.log ('In getAnotherItem');
   getAnotherItem.findOne({ some_id : some_id}, function(err, getAnotherItemRet){
      //console.log ('In getAnotherItem Callback');
      res.send({
         itemName : getAnotherItemRet.itemName,
         itemValue : getAnotherItemRet.itemValue;
      });
   })
});
```

I get the following sequence of messages on the console...

```
In getItem
In getAnotherItem
In getItem callback
In getAnotherItem callback
```

I am assuming because the route does not finish, it calls next() automatically.

Q: How do I prevent the second route from being called automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to understand why you get messages in that order, we need to know what url are you calling to generate that message.

In any case though, "/api/getItem" does not call "/api/getAnotherItem" for two reasons:

1. if you call next in "/api/getItem", it will call the next matching route, in this case, it will match either a route on "/api", "/" or nothing at all. the next() function basically calls the route's "parent".
2. Next() must be called explicitly, if you do not return an answer, express will simply wait indefinitely until res.send is called (which is how it can handle async functions).

It's possible you have some kind of middleware (I.E. used with app.use and not app.get) which could call something like that, but most likely, you are calling both urls at the same time somehow.

Comment: Thank you Illniyar. Good catch...I was actually calling both urls simultanously. I had rearranged the code and started to see this problem. Hence assumed it was an issue with the routes.

Answer (score 4):

Try reversing `req` and `res`:

```
// wrong
exports.getItem = function (res, req) {
// right
exports.getItem = function (req, res) {
```

(and same for `getAnotherItem`).

Comment: My apologies - it is (req, res). For simplicity, I edited the code and accidently reversed it before I asked the question here. I have edited the question above. Thank you for pointing out.